# How to recursively compare properties in C# test case

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a type structure like this:

```
    class Address
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        protected bool Equals(Address other) => Id == other.Id;
        public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Address)obj);
        }
    }

    class PrivateAddress : Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
    }

    record Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

And with this structure, I have these two persons:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestPerson()
    {
        var person1 = new Person
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Address = new PrivateAddress
            {
                Id = "1",
                Street = "1st Street"
            }
        };
        var person2 = new Person
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Address = new PrivateAddress
            {
                Id = "1",
                Street = "2nd Street"
            }
        };
    }
```

They are obviously not equal, the streets are different. I want my tests to reflect this.

I tried [DeepEquals](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepEqual/):

```
        person1.ShouldDeepEqual(person2);
```

And [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/):

```
        person1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(person2);
```

Both do not work (the tests succeed instead of failing). I assume because they use only `Equals()` for the comparison of the addresses. But its correct that these types only get compared by ID, so I can't change that only to make the tests work.

Is there a way to compare these objects property by property recursively?

Comment: Override Equals in PrivateAddress if you need compare also the Street property. Make your Equals(Address other) virtual.

Comment: @Victor I do not need to compare the `Street` property. In fact it would be wrong to compare it, too.

Comment: If your comparison only use Id, the tests are ok: both of them are equals. If need compare more properties, you need create other method, like CompareContent, for example. But I think you must use Equals to compare content (is the expected) and other method like "SimilarId" to compare only the Ids.

Comment: This isn't "recursively" testing properties. You're checking "nested" properties. Recursive means that the nested properties are of the same type meaning that you could nest forever.

Comment: Overriding Equals for the object you  want to compare would be the best solution. You can check there whatever you want.
And if you want to check nested properties, just implement your program with right structure using `polymorphizm` and override Equals on every level if you want it to behave different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone that has the same use-case (`Equals()` that does not compare all properties, but tests where you want to make sure your properties are set in a specific way), the very professional way to do this is:

```
Assert.AreEqual(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person1), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person2));
```

This will even print you a pretty nice error message when failing:

```
String lengths are both 65. Strings differ at index 35.
  Expected: "...me":"Bob","Address":{"Street":"1st Street","City":"Dresden"}}"
  But was:  "...me":"Bob","Address":{"Street":"2nd Street","City":"Dresden"}}"
  ---------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: This is a very expensive way to do this. You would want to know precisely what you're doing with this object.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's a test case? Why would I care about "expensive" at development time? At least this way I do not need to change anything if the type's properties get changed in the future.

Comment: It's expensive at run-time, not development time.

Comment: @Enigmativity And tests are run while developing, never during the lifecycle of the finished product. So whether I have the above test, a better version of the property comparison (which from the answers doesn't seem to exist) or no test at all will not change the run-time of my application.

Comment: That still doesn't change any of my comments. They still stand.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what exact behavior you are after.

Your current implementation only uses the Id for equality. Therefor the two addresses are considered equal even if the streets are different. So I'm not sure why you saying that the two addresses are obviously not equal, you just defined them as being equal.  You might want consider if you want to allow a PrivateAddress to be equal to a Address if they share the same Id.

If you want *value equality* the two addresses are unequal since they have different streets, to get this behavior you need to override the equality methods in the PrivateAddress class. Another way to get value equality would be to use a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) or struct instead of a class, since these have value equality by default.

If you want *reference equality* you should not override any equals methods, since it is the default behavior for classes. You could also call `ReferenceEquals` to explicitly check for reference equality.

If you want to use different types of equality in different circumstances you should use the [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0) interface and provide different comparers for different use cases. Methods that need to compare objects should take a IEqualityComparer parameter. So you can have one implementation that only uses the ID for equality, and one that compares all properties.

You might also consider implementing [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-6.0) since this provides typed equality methods.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you have defined `Equals` on `Address` to be `bool Equals(Address other) => Id == other.Id;`. This means that any object that is an `Address` is equal to the current `Address` if, and only if, the Ids match.

You can't later change your mind if the object is an address of a different subclass.

And what if we had this:

```
    var person1 = new Person
    {
        Name = "Bob",
        Address = new PrivateAddress
        {
            Id = "1",
            Street = "1st Street"
        }
    };
    var person2 = new Person
    {
        Name = "Bob",
        Address = new Address
        {
            Id = "1",
        }
    };
```

What should happen now? Are they equal?

In any case, you should implement the standard `Equals` correctly to try to avoid this situation.

Try this:

```
class Address
{
    public string Id { get; init; } = "";

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is Address other)
        {
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class PrivateAddress : Address
{
    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is PrivateAddress other)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj) && this.Street == other.Street;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode() ^ this.Street.GetHashCode();
    }
    
    public string Street { get; init; } = "";
}
```

Now, if you do that your test fails, as you wanted.

The only issue remaining is if your first address is `Address` and the second is `PrivateAddress` - this will pass. If you swapped them around then they would fail. Your problem is the substitution principle. Any `Address` should work the same way, you're changing that way, and that breaks the priciple.

Answer (score -2):

Could you use an extension method like this, it will compare each property of two objects and check if they are equal?

```
public static bool EqualsRecursive(this T a, T b)
{
    foreach (var propa in a.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propb = b.GetType(). GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == propa.Name).Single();
        if (propb.GetValue(b, null) != propa.GetValue(a, null))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I guess you could then use the extension method on the comparison between `propa` and `propb` to recursively drill down the nested properties.

Comment: The OP has given full classes and sample data. If your method works you should show that it does, rather than guess.

Answer (score -2):

You have a `GetHashCode` method override which uses the id property which is `1` in both cases. Change the value of the `Id` property from either one of the two items and the test will not likely pass.

Comment: The tests already pass. That's the problem. And the `GetHashCode()` method is implemented correctly for the use-case, I shouldn't need to change it to accommodate the tests.

Comment: The method is implemented correctly, but the test data has `1` for both options, so it will generate the same hashcode for either one and then comparisatie will result in equality.

Comment: Why is this not the correct answer? I want to learn...

Comment: It is not the correct answer, because it does not answer the question at all. The question was how to compare objects property by property in a test case.

Comment: @StefanS. how clumsy of me, i was completely focussed on the tests and not realizing that was a effect and not the cause.